# Matlab profiling

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to speed up my code in Matlab through profiling. I have two questions:

1) when I call the profile report I get a list of functions; most of them are not explicitly called by my code (e.g. `workspacefunc`); how can I see to which lines of my code they are referred?

2) What is the function `workspacefunc`?

Comment: 1- Even if function are not explicitly "visually" called from your code, some builtin Matlab functions call other functions inside, so they are calledd from your code.

Comment: ok, but how can I find where they are called from my code?

Comment: If you click te name of the function in the profiler it will show you an specific page for that function. In the beggining there is somewhere whre you can read "parent", wich is the function that is calling the current one.

Comment: Well... In my code, when I run an .m file, even the functions called in the main file have a parent, wich is the .m file itself. I have never crossed the situation of not having a parent, so I dont know :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do anything else between `profile on` and `profile viewer` except run the code you're trying to check, other actions you take will also be included in the profiler.

For example, running the standard example:

```
profile on
plot(magic(35))
profile viewer
```

Should show you that most of the time is actually consumed by `setdiff` (if ordered by Self Time).  `workspacefunc` is not listed.

If after calling `plot(magic(35))`, you then go to the plot and zoom in a bit, then call `profile viewer`, you will see that some functions related to `zoom` are now in the list.  The code itself, of course, doesn't actually `zoom` anything.

And if after calling `plot(magic(35))`, you double-click on a variable in the Workspace browser, then run `profile viewer`, you will see `workspacefunc`, and a bunch of other things which weren't there before, appear in the list.